# LEFT JOIN CONCAT('hello_',c.id) possible?

Tags: php, mysql, join, concatenation

IS it possible to have something like this:

SELECT c.id as id
FROM Channels c
LEFT JOIN CONCAT('hello_',c.id)

I NEED this concat with the c.id. THERE IS NO OTHER WAY.
So any tips?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you please share your table(s) structure, some sample data and the result your're trying to achieve?

Comment: I need a TABLE NAME hello_c.id 
For every row at Channels there's a table named hello_<id from Channels row> ... the same as hello_c.id

Comment: From what I'm understanding I'd take a step back and look and your database model and rethink.

Comment: That's like: oh i don't know how to do it so you're wrong because "books" told me not to.
If everyone would follow these kind of "rules" facebook or google would never ever exist. That's exactly what i heard from Zuckerberg when i met him in dev meeting he was giving some speech for in the early stage of facebook... so dynamic names for these tables are necessary and that's it. i won't change it.

Anyone?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We who answer questions here are volunteers. Some of us have lots of experience. With respect, you will probably find that mutual respect will produce more useful answers than statements that people are narrowminded. MySQL is open-source. If you think It should handle variables as table names go ahead and submit a patch to the MySQL (or MariaDB) team. At the time you asked your question, you can't use variables for table names in queries.

Comment: Look, we are here to help you with your attempt to ask a question. You didn't make clear at first what you want to achieve (instead you SHOUTED to us) and now you're getting snotty because people doubt your DB design. Good luck!

Comment: By the way, I think you mean `LEFT JOIN` rather than `JOIN LEFT`.

Comment: Humm... a tip for you , **learn** how to programm here: codecademy.com

Answer (score 2):

You asked whether you can use an expression involving column values and functions like CONCAT to generate table names in queries in MySQL.

The short answer is **no.**

There's a longer answer involving MySQL prepared statements. That's basically a way to use string processing in a MySQL stored procedure to generate the text of a query to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to do it at SQL level: it is not possible. Table name tokens are not computed from expressions.

However, with php and creating a query dynamically, it should be quite trival to use a "modified" table name according to your need.
So, your `concat()` should be a php expression when building the query.

In the case where you are trying  to join a (different) table based on the column value of a base table, you are far from any SQL semantics.

In that case you might want to rearrange your schema to merge all table instances identified by what your concat is now trying to compute info a single table and label each row with the *logical* table it belongs to.

Comment: YES i already have it in separated queries in PHP. But i wanted to achieve it within a single query.
But yes, at least you gave a real answer instead of some who actually spam any Question just to get points with useless answers. No..no.. actually with no answers like at all.
Thx